# Nuxt run build failed, but dev is fine (loader to handle this file type)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I use nuxt.js with Vue

I have a problem with running a project in build mode (npm run build). In development mode the project starts (npm run dev -> 0 errors and localhost:3000 working)

I tried to delete .nuxt folder, node-modules and lock file, try yarn and npm, I tried different options - one result

When I try "npm run build" I have that's 41 errors with in ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/

```
    ERROR  Failed to compile with 41 errors                                                                        22:48:24

    error  in ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/components/layout/col.js

    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (100:4)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    |     cols: strNum(),
    |     // Breakpoint Specific props
    |     ...breakpointCol,
    |     offset: strNum(),
    |     ...breakpointOffset,

    @ ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/components/layout/index.js 3:0-24
    @ ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/components/index.js
    @ ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.js
    @ ./.nuxt/bootstrap-vue.js
    @ ./.nuxt/index.js
    @ ./.nuxt/client.js

    error  in ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/components/toast/helpers/bv-toast.js

    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (107:6)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    |     // Preset the prop values
    |     propsData: {
    |       ...filterOptions(getComponentConfig('BToast') || {}),
    |       // Add in (filtered) user supplied props
    |       ...omit(props, ['toastContent']),

    @ ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/components/toast/index.js 3:0-47
    @ ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/components/index.js
    @ ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/src/index.js
    @ ./.nuxt/bootstrap-vue.js
    @ ./.nuxt/index.js
    @ ./.nuxt/client.js
```

my nuxt.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "spa",
  head: {
    title: "nuxt-template",
    meta: [ { charset: "utf-8" },
      { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
      { hid: "description", name: "description", content: "Nuxt.js project" } ],
    link: [ { rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" } ],
    script: [ { src: "/js/signalr.js" } ]
  },
  css: ["~assets/scss/coreui.scss"],
  loading: {
    color: "#3B8070"
  },
  plugins: ["~/plugins/bootstrap-vue", "~/plugins/vue-notifications", "~/plugins/mixin", "~/plugins/vue-tables-2", "~/plugins/moment.js", "~/plugins/vue-text-mask.js", "~/plugins/vue-clipboard2.js"],
  build: {
    analyze: true,
    vendor: ["axios", "bootstrap-vue", "vue-notifications", "mini-toastr", "js-cookie", "jwt-decode", "vuelidate", "vue-tables-2", "moment", "vue-text-mask", "vue-select", "vue-clipboard2", "vue-qrcode-component"],
    extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      if (isClient) {
        config.devtool = "eval-source-map";
      }
      if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: "pre",
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: "eslint-loader",
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        });
      }
    }
  },
  modules: [ [ "bootstrap-vue/nuxt", { css: false } ] ]
};
```

What handler does it ask to handle this type of file? How can I add the appropriate loader to handle this file type?

Comment: Whats is ~/plugins/bootstrap-vue ? You have  a bootstrap-vue/nuxt module and so there shouldnt be any plugin for it.
And i hope u are on latest nuxt, and if so - vendor option is deprecated

Comment: try disable plugins: [  //"~/plugins/bootstrap-vue" ....] and  vendor: [ //"bootstrap-vue" .... ] have now error ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"minimize":true,"importLoaders":1,"alias":{"/assets":"C://Users//Delari//source//repos//GBPay//GBPay.DashBoardNuxt//assets","/static":"C://Users//Delari//source//repos//GBPay//GBPay.DashBoardNuxt//static"}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-77b00b2b","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":true}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader

Comment: Create a reproduction of your problem on codesandbox otherwise it's impossible to tell

Comment: Thanks for the help and guidance where there may be a problem, I solved my problem

Comment: Can you oi please post your solution to the problem? I'm having exact same issue and I'd be very grateful! Thanks in advance!